# Test if Suds Client Has Timed Out

Tags: python, suds

I have a class which is using SOAP to download data from a web API. What I'd like to do is have the instance of the class instantiate the client once on construction, and then use the same client for all subsequent operations, unless the connection has timed out. In that case it should create a new client.

The class makes multiple requests, processes some data, and then goes on to make subsequent requests based on the results of the data processing. So the time between requests can be quite variable.

Is there a simple way to test whether or not the client has timed out? Or am I better off just setting the timeout to be really long/creating a new client for each request?

Ideally I'd like to be able to so something like this:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.wsse import Security, UsernameToken

def create_client(self):

    if self.client.timed_out():

         token = UsernameToken(self.username, self.password)
         security = Security().tokens.append(token)
         client = Client(self.wsdl)
         client.set_options(wsse=security)

         self.client = client
```